# Cannot implicitly convert type for interface

Tags: c#

There is some duplicate of similar thread in stackoverflow but this is not exact same, so I post here again. Let's consider the following example.

```
  public interface ILeft
    {
        void Move();
    }

    public class MoveableOject : ILeft
    {
        //without public we get an error
        public void Move()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Left moving");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MoveableOject mo = new MoveableOject();
            mo.Move();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

All are fine. Now let's consider the explicit implementation of ILeft. Why does the commented line give above error message?

```
 class MoveableOject : ILeft
{
    void ILeft.Move()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Left moving");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MoveableOject mo = new MoveableOject();
       // MoveableOject moWithErrorObject = (ILeft) new MoveableOject(); <--
        ((ILeft)mo).Move();
        ((ILeft)new MoveableOject()).Move();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Edit: 8th Nov/2015 MoveableOject in the error statement should be ILeft understandable, mistakenly I put it there. Why I post it the reason I could not explain it, let's use the object and passed to a method in the following way.

```
public static void ExpectDerivedPassedDerived(MoveableOject passedObject)
{
    passedObject.Move();
}
```

Now if I call the method from Main should it work? But it does not because I have explicit implementation but if I implement with public keyword then this will be fine, I was looking an explanation of this.

```
 ExpectDerivedPassedDerived(mo);  //mo is MoveableOject type
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with explicit interfaces. `MoveableObject` inherits from `ILeft`, not the other way round.

Comment: Explicit implementation allows your method to only be accessible when cast as the interface itself. ILeft in this case.

Comment: Can anybody comment on the edited code? That was my original intention to ask the question. Thanks.

Comment: I comment a little late and maybe you already know, but the problem you mention in your comment from 8th Nov/2015 is that the class `MoveableOject` implements the interface `ILeft` explicitly. In such a case we have to access the object `passedObject` through the interface explicitly, `((ILeft)passedObject).Move()`. Good article is e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation).

Answer (score 2):

You create a new `MoveableOject`, cast it as `ILeft`, and then you try to assing the `ILeft` you got from cast to a MoveableObject reference. Compliler disagree, as expected

```
Ileft iLeftReference = getILeft();
MoveableOject mObj = iLeftReference; // same error
```

Answer (score 2):

The error that you are observing has nothing to do with explicit implementation of `ILeft`. Actually that's because of `assignment compatibility`.
We can only assign more derived objects to less derived objects, not vice versa.

You cannot do:

```
MoveableOject moWithErrorObject = (ILeft) new MoveableOject();
```

As `MoveableOject` is more derived than it's parent `ILeft`.

You can get some details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee207183.aspx).